# How to find which system is broadcasting in network

Tags: windows, ip, wifi, netgear

I have netgear N150 wireless router model WGR614. I am receiving Google search captcha confirmation for some searches.With message that Google is receiving  a lot of requests from our network.
How I can find out which system is broad casing.
Please help me.

Comment: This (the Google CAPTCHA) is typically caused by malware on your system(s). I'd suggest running MalwareBytes Anti-Malware or a good antivirus on your machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're describing isn't a broadcast-- it's just requests to a web site.

That router device doesn't support port-mirroring, so you're in a bit of a challenging situation. Ideally, you'd wedge a computer between the router and the ISP on the LAN side of the firewall and sniff the traffic to determine which machine is generating the excessive requests. Since you don't have that option I think you're going to be stuck doing a binary search-- disconnect half of the clients and see if the problem goes away, repeat until you find the "half" containing the malfunctioning client, then winnow that group down.

If you're running an open wifi network or using weak encryption then, ultimately, you may find that unauthorized clients are the culprit. Malware is also a likely culprit.

Comment: I want to put a system in between ISP and router. can you guide mehow to do it? means set up proxy server in windows or linux or any other solution ?